# Restore my system to factory settings

Tags: dual-boot, windows, restore

I have SONY VAIO with windows 7 pre installed. I have installed the UBUNTU in other partition to work as dual boot. I am trying now to restore the factory settings with ALT + F10 which is not working any more. Each time its giving me screen to choose operating system. How do I restore my system now?

Comment: Do you want to remove Ubuntu (grub) and return to a PC with only Windows installed?

Comment: @ninad116 Yes I want to keep windows only

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to delete Ubuntu and  restore Windows to original state (factory settings)? 
Note that I'm not familiar with Vaio, however on boot screen (grub) you should be able to see installed systems. For Windows you should have more than one entry and the first one `sda/dev1` (or similar most likely) is rescue partition of Windows. Boot there and  follow to guide to re-install Windows.

Hope it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Vaio in particular, but these days most computers come with a hidden 'rescue' partition that's used to 'restore factory settings'. That it doesn't work for you could indicate that you have deleted this partition (perhaps when installing Ubuntu).

Take a look at the partition table (eg. with gparted) and check if there's an extra partition you don't use; it'll probably be 10-20 GiB in size, and may be hidden, labeled 'Rescue' or somesuch, and formatted with either NTFS or FAT. If it's there, try editing your grub configuration to show it as a boot option from the menu -- perhaps it's just that the BIOS is confused by the partition layout, but if you boot it directly it'll work fine.

If it isn't there, then the only way to reimage the system ('restore to factory settings') is to use an external rescue media you probably could have made on first Windows boot. If you don't have it, I'm afraid you need to contact Sony tech support.

Comment: The restore partition is still there and I have not deleted it. I did check it and SONY VIAO comes with restore partition as I have paid windows 7 in my laptop. How do I change the GRAB settings?

Comment: @Umar Are you getting option on boot to select which OS to boot into? If you are, there should be an option to boot in Windows (recovery) partition.

Comment: As @danijelc mentions, perhaps it's already there? Examine the grub menu and see if there isn't a restore entry there.

Comment: Also note that it's possible that Vaio BIOS tries to use a boot parameter for windows instead of booting the recovery partition; this would explain why it fails to activate it. I'm not an expert on windows, but if this is the case, you might try to enter Windows boot menu (IIRC you need to press F8 on boot -- right after you choose windows from the grub menu) and see if there's a recovery option in there.

Comment: http://snag.gy/soplq.jpg are the current disks on my system

Comment: As already mentioned this shows that first partition on your drive is recovery partition for Windows, Now could you please check and see if is listed on you grub (windows) recovery partition on sda/dev1 and if listed boot there and  re-install the windows?

Comment: Umm just rechecked your picture there your recovery disk looks empty? Did you delete it when installing Ubuntu? did u Used wubi or made a live CD/USB installation?

Comment: @danijelc, I believe this only means it's not mounted. Also, I note it's active -- probably the BIOS did it. So if it's not shown in grub, simply restoring MBR will also boot it.

Comment: Maybe @Divide, Windows should see how much space is allocated no matter if not mounted. Thing is unless Umar clears what he sees from grub it's kinda hard to help him, and if partition was wiped he will need a Windows boot DVD to restore on factory default

Answer (score 0):

You should go through answers of  question [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/q/133533/212399) before proceeding. I believe you will be redirected to the correct way to do it after referring to this question.